# Elastic Search Remove Unassigned Shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with the shards in Elastic Search. Whenever I create my index it creates an unassigned node with unassigned shards as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone please help me out here? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simply because you have only one node and one shard replica is always created by default.

In order to prevent this, you can remove the replicas from your index by calling this:

```
PUT suppliercloudproductindex1/_settings
{
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0
}
```

Alternately, you can also specify this setting when initially creating your index in order to make sure that no replica shard gets created:

```
PUT suppliercloudproductindex1
{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: @val..i did try both the steps but it's still the same. Do I need to create the index if I am using the first option? Although I have the setting defined in my index creation

Comment: The first one is to fix an existing index, the second one is to make sure an index is not created with replicas

Comment: I did both but they still stay the same.

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get when clicking on "Info > Index metadata" ?

Answer (score 0):

`PUT */_settings { "index.number_of_replicas": 0 }`

This will update all indexes to have zero replicas.  This will only work if wild card operations are allowed.  Otherwise the command has to be run on every index in your cluster.

Comment: You also might have more success using Kibana rather than Head..